# Beginner to datasets - readings suggestion

Tags: c#

I am a beginner to .Net. Recently I am working on a small practice project in which i want to interact with SQL DB using Datasets in VS .net 2008. Kindly suggest me few readings regarding Typed Datasets.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to work with datasets (and ado.net in general), I would recommend [Microsoft ADO.Net Core Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?id=5354&locale=en-us). The book is dated now, but in my opinion, so is using datasets. Either way, you can't beat that book in my opinion. The [follow up book](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?id=8744&locale=en-us), which covers ADO.Net 2.0 is more modern and done *almost* as well as the original (though the original will teach you more about how everything works).

Answer (score 1):

you can google these things. however check the below links  
[MSDN Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)
[Creation of Typed DataSet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714)

Answer (score 1):

A search in google for DataSet Examples C# turned the following results:

[DataSet examples C#](http://www.google.bg/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=bg&source=hp&q=DataSet+examples+C#&pbx=1&oq=DataSet+examples+C#&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2163l2689l1l3009l3l0l0l3l3l0l0l0ll3l0&fp=1&biw=1280&bih=580&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b)

Are you sure you want to use DataSet? There are a better techniques now for accessing and manipulating data.

**Update:**
Depending on your needs there are other ways to access data.
If you need speed - you will probably need to use **SqlDataReader**.
If you need ease of use, you may skip the more "core" ways of accessing data and use **Entity Framework**.

[Retrieving data with Sql Data Reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Getting started with Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx)

The difference is that SQL Data Reader is the most native way of accessing data. It it uses something like cursor you iterate over.

Entity Framework on the other hand is a fully featured OR/M solution for Microsoft Visual Studio, you basically tell Visual Studio where your data is and it will generate the data classes for you. From there - you just use those classes. It is really easy to use but it uses reflection under the hood which makes it a bit slower than the Sql Data Reader.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Suggest me a better technique then, I guess as far as i have found, datasets are easy to understand.

Comment: See my update. Just to clarify a bit further - SQL Data Reader is probably a better way if you are in a very heavy environment with a lot of calls to the DB. Anyway, in most cases Entity Framework will fit just fine + it gives a really easy to use interface.